# Access-logged document (web)

Tags: web-apps, security

Need a simple free web app that can store something as basic as text,
with all (read) access  logged.

Think of it as a cryptpad / gdocs / protectedtext.com, but if I open the note and read it then do it once again later, those accesses are all logged (datetime/uagent/screensize/ip/etc).

Ideally it should also log "when the tab is closed".